# How to Style a Ul Li with CSS to make it look like a "form" dropdown list?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a Ul Li with some links , they display like a menu.
I want to set a "dropdown" list but like the classic "form" selectors... 
-not a drop-down menu that shows on hover, but a clickable menu.

```
<ul>
<li>Option 1 </li>
<li>Option 2 </li>
</ul>
```

Which CSS would make it look like a "form dropdown"?

I attach image to make it clear to what I need:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNeoo.png

Comment: check this tutorial:http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, for some reason, you want to keep it as a list. You'll need more than CSS.

Step 1- In the HTML, put the list inside a  and also add some HTML to style as the select box. e.g.

```
<div class="dropdown-emulator">
  <div class="dropdown-emulator-selected"></div>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-emulator-select-btn">v</a>
  <ul>
    <li>Option 1 </li>
    <li>Option 2 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Step 2- Add CSS to style this to the way you desire. Mainly you'll want to position the list to underneath the box and then display:none.

```
.dropdown-emulator{
  position:relative;
}

.dropdown-emulator ul{
  position:absolute;
  top:25px;
  left:0;
}
```

Step 3- Create some JavaScript to capture the onclick event of the select button to make the list appear.

For a very basic working example see here http://jsfiddle.net/q5SEF/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think for this, you probably want to use a  field, using  tags?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Alternatively.

You could trigger a jQuery visibility toggle on a hidden div, which would show the content of your dropdown, when it is clicked.

Comment: Be wary of w3fools :P

Comment: @berkeleybross - It would seem in this case that the OP is relatively new to web development. Whilst I would ordinarily* directly refer to the w3c, in this case that information may have been overwhelming. As such, I decided to offer this resource as a link.

* In a professional capacity

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is a dropdown select. In stead of having a list of items use a select tag.

```
<select id="mydropdown">
  <option value="Milk">Fresh Milk</option>
  <option value="Cheese">Old Cheese</option>
  <option value="Bread">Hot Bread</option>
</select>
```